# + operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++

I have a use case
If I have 5 classes A,B,C,D,E and their instances as a,b,c,d,e

If there is an expression
a = b +  c + d + e;

What is the order of invocation of operator+ and operator=.
Also what would be the temporary object created.

Can you please help me

Comment: If you overload those operators, you can use a debugger, or diagnostic output, to determine the order. What happens when you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is left associative. `=` is right associative. The order would be

- `d` + `e` makes a temporary `de`
- `de` + `c` makes temporary `cde`. This is done by a call to class `C`'s operator `+` taking an argument of whatever class the temporary `de` is an instance of.
- `cde` + `b` makes temporary `bcde`. This is done by a call to class `B`'s operator `+` taking an argument of the class of `cde`.
- The value of `bcde` is assigned to variable `a`.

Temporaries here are a general case, it depends on what you actually do with your overload what will happen. The class to the left of the temporary will be called using that temporary as an argument, not the other way around.

While the evaluation goes from left to right when using `+`, the actual computation goes the other way.

Comment: So class D's operator+ would be called first which is like operator+(E   & e). So based on what it returns say D/E object, that objects operator+ would be called OR Class C's operator+ be called?

Comment: Yes, it goes right to left and you cannot be sure of the temporaries as others have said it depends on your implementation and the compiler you are using. Try it out using a debugger, it's probably the best way to see it in action!

Comment: Class `C`s operator + will be called with the temporaries return type.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = b + c + d + e;
```

The expression on the r.h.s of `=` will be evaluated first and then `=` will be called to assign that result to variable on l.h.s.

The expression on the r.h.s will be evaluated from right to left.

Check **[operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence)**.

Also, note that generation of temporary in this case will be depend upon:

- Implementation of the overloaded `+` operator &
- Compiler in use

Comment: Just a note, but operator precedence does **not** control the order the operator overload functions are called.  (Except indirectly, here, since the precedence creates operand dependencies.)

Answer (score 0):

Full reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The additions are executed first, from right to left. The assignment is the last to get executed. Depending on optimizations, there might not be any temporary produced:

```
   int x,y,z,k;
   x = y = z = k = 3;
   int l = x + y + z + k;
   cout << l;
00401000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (402038h)] 
00401006  push        0Ch  
00401008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (40203Ch)]
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how there cannot be a temporary.  Any reasonable implementation of `operator+` will return a temporary, and there's no copy to a non-temporary which can be elided.  So I think there must be at least three temporaries.

Comment: @JamesKanze I updated my answer with the most obvious example I could think of.

Comment: You can't tell whether there was a temporary or not with `int`.  We're talking about user defined `operator+` here, returning a class type.  (Otherwise, the question about temporaries doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @JamesKanze oh I see your point now. However, I still think that under some constraints, this can still be optimized.

Comment: In theory, all that is required is that the "observable behavior" be respected.  The standard doesn't place any constraints per se on generated code; except that it behave "as if" the abstract semantics (which do include the temporaries) are respected.  In that sense, anything can be "optimized out".  In my mind, in cases like this, we are talking about the semantics of the program, and not the generated code.  There is also a case where optimization is allowed to change the observable behavior: the eliding of copy constructors.  I don't think that that applies here.

Comment: @JamesKanze in that case, you're completely right. I sometimes fail to see the semantic meaning of the question. I guess I should be more thorough in my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not a homework

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

```
+ precedence is higher than =
```

so + first, and it reads from left to right

then =, and it reads from right to left

For the temporary object, sorry i don't know about it.

Comment: nah! I have a project where I am adding custom math objects. Int, Complex Number, vector ....

Comment: i see. For the temp. object, obviously if it is original gcc without optimization, b + c turns to a temp object bc and then continues + d and so on. For the calculation, if all the variables inside your class are primitive type, you don't need to overload any + or = operator, c++ takes care for you. otherwise you need to handle your "plus" logic yourselfs :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no sequence points, so the only constraints are that the 
arguments to an operator must be evaluated before the operator itself is
called.  In your case:

```
a = b + c + d + e;
```

means:

```
a = (((b + c) + d) + e);
```

which becomes:

```
a.operator=( operator+( operator+( operator+( b, c ), d), e ) );
```

(I'm assuming here that `operator=` is a member, as is required by the
standard, but that `operator+` is a free function, as is usual.)

As it happens, in this particular expression, operand dependencies
impose a strict order.

As for the temporaries, it depends on the implementation of `operator+`,
but to give the operator it's usual semantics, it is necessary that each
call return a temporary (and not a reference).  In this case, you will
have 3 temporaries, once created at the return from each `operator+`,
and all destructed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: Are you sure this is right, I thought that it would be as if you had written a = b + (c + (d + e)); as + is left to right associative? I may be wrong...

Comment: @JohnB The production is _additive-expression_ : _additive-expression_ + _multiplicative-expression_.  So in `a + b + c`, `a + b` gets reduced first.  This is what I understand by left associative as well: the operator to the left is grouped first.  (This corresponds to the explication in Wikipedia too.)

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution is unchanged by the overloading. The normal C++ operator precedence and operand evaluation rules apply.